# Can't config path alias for typescript + vite + vuejs

Tags: typescript, vite

I been search around, and tried a few methods, tutorials but none of them works. So i'm not sure if things has changed or i did something not right.

Let say i have folder like this:

`/src/components/TheWelcome.vue`

Instead of absolute import like above i want to make it shorter like

`@components/TheWelcome.vue`

Or incase deeper level like:

`/src/first/second/third/forth/MyComponent.vue`

will be:

`@forth/MyComponent.vue`

So i tried with a brandnew vue project using `pnpm install vue@latest` for vue+typescript+eslint+prettier

And below are mine setup:

```json
\\tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*", "./dist/*", ""],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@forth/*": ["./src/first/second/third/forth/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
\\vite.config.ts
// import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
      '@components': `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/')}`,
      '@forth': `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src/first/second/third/forth/')}`
    }
  }
})
```

[error screen on type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5mF4.png)
[file and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GqMI.png)

I tried to do the config for both tsconfig and vite with many ways that show on stackoverflow and some other blog but none works.

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many times i'm able to fix it. Turn off i need to have this line in tsconfig file

```
"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
```

but lots of tutorial don't inluded it in the file so i don't know about it. Anyway these config solve my problem if anyone hit the same problem can give it a try

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "comp/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "forth/*": ["src/first/second/third/forth/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"] // must add this line
}
```

```js
//vite.config.ts


import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { URL, fileURLToPath } from 'url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      comp: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/components/', import.meta.url)),
      forth: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/first/second/third/forth/', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```